# Existence of convergent sequences vs boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I noticed the following two conclusions in a textbook but couldn't figure out how to start the proof.

Given a set $I:=\{x|0<|x-x_0|<\delta\}$ and assume that function $f(x)$ is defined on $I$.

**Conclusion 1:** If $f(x)$ is bounded on $I$, then there must exist a convergent sequence {$x_n\} \in I$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=x_0$ and $f(x_n)$ is convergent.

**Conclusion 2:** If $f(x)$ is unbounded on $I$, then there must exist a convergent sequence {$x_n\}\in I$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=x_0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

I am new to this area. Hence, any hints and suggestions for the proof are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For the first conclusion, you can define a trivial sequence $x_n = x_1 \in I$ for all $n$ and for which we know that $f(x_1)$ exists and is bounded.

For the second conclusion: we know that $f(x)$ is not bounded on $I$ so for all $n \in N$ there exists a number $x_n$ in $I$ for which $f(x_n) > n$. Note that this collection of numbers (sequence) $x_n$ is bounded so according to the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem it has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$. This subsequence is convergent to some $x_0$ in $I$ but $f(x_{n_k})$ is divergent.

Comment: For the first condition, set $I$ does not contain $x_0$ here. I have removed "neighborhood" to avoid further confusion.

Comment: I updated the answer. Since $f(x)$ is bounded on $I$, there must some $x_1$ in $I$ for which the function is defined. You can make a trivial sequence on that point.

Comment: These conditions require the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converge to $x_0$ which is a given point in the setting.